# PHP Error 500 when trying to make a simple grading system

Tags: php

I am trying to create a simple grading system where if a certain value is inputted in a textbox and submitted, it will show a grade on the next page, what I get instead is an error 500 code, I believe it has something to do with the way I'm writing the code.

I'm not sure whether writing it like this is correct:

if($a <= 60) {
echo = "F" }

elseif...

```
    <body>
        <center>
            <div class="container">
                <form action="cek_grade.php" method="post"> <!--Action: Sent to "cek_grade.php" Method: The data will be displayed by "post"-->
                   Nilai: <input type="integer" name="nilai"> <!--The name of the numbers inputted are "nilai"-->
                   <br><br>
                   <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                   <input type="reset" id="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
                </form> <!--All the data above should get sent to the page called "cek_grade.php"-->
            </div>
       </center>
    </body>

<?php

        nilai = $_POST ['nilai'];
        echo = "$nilai"

        if($nilai <= 60) {
        echo = "F"
        } elseif ($nilai <= 70) {
        echo="C"
        } elseif ($nilai <= 80) {
        echo="B"
        } else {
        echo="A"

>
```

What I'm trying to do is if variable "$nilai" is a certain range of value,, it will display a grade of either F, C, B or A

Comment: `echo = "F"` makes no sense. You're looking for `echo "F"` -- you can't assign to an `echo`. Also you appear to have forgotten the `$` in `nilai` along with most of your semicolons, and you can't have a space after `$_POST` in `$_POST ['nilai']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your script:

- Your first reference to `$nilai` is missing the `$`.
- You can't assign to `echo`.
- You're missing a semicolon at the end of most lines.
- You have an invalid space in `$POST ['nilai]`.

Here's a working version:

```
$nilai = $_POST['nilai'];
echo "$nilai";

if($nilai <= 60) {
    echo "F";
} elseif ($nilai <= 70) {
    echo "C";
} elseif ($nilai <= 80) {
    echo "B";
} else {
    echo "A";
}
```

Comment: echo "$nilai";
This is a variable how can you use it inside quotes

Answer (score 0):

You missed a lot of things

```
<body>
        <center>
            <div class="container">
                <form action="cek_grade.php" method="post"> <!--Action: Sent to "cek_grade.php" Method: The data will be displayed by "post"-->
                   Nilai: <input type="integer" name="nilai"> <!--The name of the numbers inputted are "nilai"-->
                   <br><br>
                   <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                   <input type="reset" id="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
                </form> <!--All the data above should get sent to the page called "cek_grade.php"-->
            </div>
       </center>
    </body>

<?php
    $nilai = $_POST['nilai'];
    echo $nilai;

    if($nilai <= 60) {
      echo "F";
    } elseif ($nilai <= 70) {
      echo "C";
    } elseif ($nilai <= 80) {
      echo "B";
    } else {
      echo "A";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will not go into HTML part but here is your corrected PHP script

```
<?php
    $nilai = $_POST ['nilai'];
    echo $nilai;

    if($nilai <= 60) {
    echo "F";
    } elseif ($nilai <= 70) {
    echo "C";
    } elseif ($nilai <= 80) {
    echo "B";
    } else {
    echo "A";
}
?>
```